# Time function with arguments in python

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, time

I have a function with a string as an argument that returns two lists

e.g.

```
def return_words(string):
    return list1, list2
```

Obviously there's code in between. I want to be able to time this function accurately for various strings as I need to improve efficiency when long strings are inputted.

Sorry if this is a trivial question as I am new to python.

Thanks

Comment: You question is unclear and broad. What do you mean by *I want to be able to time this function accurately for various strings as I need to improve efficiency when long strings are inputted.*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `timeit` module and pass the arguments in `timeit`'s `setup` argument:

```
from timeit import timeit


inp = """
def return_words(string):
    return list1, list2
return_words(string)
   """

for s in list_of_inputs:
    print '{}'.format(s), '->', timeit(stmt=inp,
                                       number=1000000,
                                       setup="string = '{}'".format(s))
```

Demo :

```
inp = """
def return_words(string):
    return [i for i in string if i.isdigit()]

return_words(string)
   """

list_of_inputs = ['inputstring1', 'inp2']

for s in list_of_inputs:
    print '{}'.format(s), '->', timeit(stmt=inp,
                                       number=1000000,
                                       setup="string = '{}'".format(s))
```

Output:

```
inputstring1 -> 0.986068964005
inp2 -> 0.548749923706
```

*Note* that `timeit` also accepts a function as the first argument which is defined in your code, but you can not pass argument to it. In that case it's better to create a wrapper which will call your function with relative arguments. Read http://pythoncentral.io/time-a-python-function/ for more info.

Comment: Is it possible to use return_words(string) as a parameter of timeit instead of stmt=inp?

Answer (score 2):

With Python 3.7, there is a new [nanosecond timer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.time_ns):

```
>>> st={time.time_ns() for e in range(10000000)}
>>> (max(st)-min(st))/10**9
2.275888
```

So a range counter (and calling `time.time_ns()` that many times) to 10,000,000 takes 2.275888 seconds...

There is also a nanosecond precision performance timer (how long does the `range` part take?):

```
>>> t1=time.perf_counter_ns(); x={y for y in range(10000000)}; t2=time.perf_counter_ns()
>>> (t2-t1)/10**9
0.860256448
```

Or the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html) module:

```
>>> timeit.timeit("x={_ for _ in range(10000000)}",number=1)
0.7478707919999579
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use time and timedelta. You can modify the code below

```
import time
from datetime import timedelta


start_time = time.time()
//do stuff
end_time = time.time()
time_slice = end_time - start_time
human_time = str(timedelta(seconds=int(time_slice)))
```